# Looking for a more concise approach to manipulate an array with nested data

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on an Angular application and want to iterate over an array of objects that have nested data. I want to mutate the existing array when a user clicks a checkbox changing the checked property from false to true and vise Versa. For simplicity sake, I'm only posting the array structure.

I tried

```
const checklistCashe = [
  {
    categories: [
      { 
        title: "Administrators",
        items: [
          {subTitle: "Admin", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Associates", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Hr", checked: false},
        ]
      },
      { 
        title: "Associates",
        items: [
          {subTitle: "Admin", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Associates", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Hr", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Users", checked: false},
        ]
      },
      { 
        title: "Organization",
        items: [
          {subTitle: "Contract", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "External", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Internal", checked: false},
        ]
      },
      { 
        title: "Products",
        items: [
          {subTitle: "Concept", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Demo", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Production", checked: false},
        ]
      },
      { 
        title: "Reporting",
        items: [
          {subTitle: "Admin", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Associates", checked: false},
          {subTitle: "Hr", checked: false},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

const category = "Reporting";
const subCategory = "Admin";
```

I want to mutate the current array based on the category and subCategory provided. So I only want the checked property to change if the title is Reporting and the subTitle is Admin.

```
{ 
  title: "Reporting",
  items: [
    {subTitle: "Admin", checked: true},
    {subTitle: "Associates", checked: false},
    {subTitle: "Hr", checked: false},
  ]
}
```

Comment: More concise than what? What's your existing code?

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

The best way with what you have would be something like:

```js
function toggleChecked(title, subtitle) {
    checklistCashe[0].categories.forEach((category) => {
        if (category.title === title) {
            category.items.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.subTitle === subtitle) {
                    item.checked = !item.checked;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

However, I feel like you might be better off formatting your checklistCashe to something more like:

```js
const checklistCashe = {
    Administrators: {
        Admin: false,
        Associates: false,
        Hr: false
    }
    [...]
}
```

Then you can do something more like:

```js
function toggleChecked(title, subtitle) {
    checklistCashe[title][subtitle] = !checklistCashe[title][subtitle]
}
```

and you wouldn't have to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested map calls:

```
function mutate (arr)
{
    return arr.map(innerArr =>
    {
        return {
            title: innerArr.title,
            items: innerArr.items.map(item => {
                return {
                    subTitle: item.subTitle,
                    checked: (innerArr.title === "Reporting" && item.subTitle === "Admin") ? false : item.checked,
                };
            }),
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep it clean then use lodash as shown below

```js
const checkListCache = [
  {
    categories: [
      {
        title: 'Administrators',
        items: [
          { subTitle: 'Admin', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Associates', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Hr', checked: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Associates',
        items: [
          { subTitle: 'Admin', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Associates', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Hr', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Users', checked: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Organization',
        items: [
          { subTitle: 'Contract', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'External', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Internal', checked: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Products',
        items: [
          { subTitle: 'Concept', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Demo', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Production', checked: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'Reporting',
        items: [
          { subTitle: 'Admin', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Associates', checked: false },
          { subTitle: 'Hr', checked: false },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const category = 'Reporting';
const subCategory = 'Admin';
const { categories } = checkListCache[0];
const selectedCategory = _.find(categories, ['title', category]);
const selectedSubCategory = _.find(selectedCategory.items, ['subTitle', subCategory]);
selectedSubCategory.checked = !selectedSubCategory.checked;

console.log(checkListCache);
```

You can add safety checks as well before each loop to ensure we have values before manipulating it.